# Configuration file format with space separator

Tags: ruby, configuration, rubygems, file-format

I need Ruby gem to work with file, that contains parameter name and it's value separated by space (say format like Unix's cfg/conf files). Below is file format example:

```
key value ; comment
foo 42
; bar comment
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [ruby-parseconfig](https://github.com/derks/ruby-parseconfig), but you should change a regexp

> param, value = line.split(/\s*=\s*/, 2)

in line `60` by replacing `=` to space (can't remember how to write space in regex in ruby)))